# Extensão PHP com Windows Erro EMIT

Tags: php, visual-studio-2015, extensão

Estou desenvolvendo uma extensão PHP com Visual Studio 2015. Segui um tutorial e tudo funcionou perfeitamente, o problema começou quando tentei usar a variável std::string. Quando eu faço o include da string eu recebo o seguinte erro de compilação:

```
variable "EMIT" is not a type name
```

meu arquivo stdafx.h:

```
    #ifdef PHP_WIN32
    #pragma once
    #include "zend_config.w32.h"
    #include "php.h"
    #endif

    #include <string> //esta linha que gera o erro.
```

Comment: Qual erro voce recebe?

Comment: variable "EMIT" is not a type name